# MouseWheel event in WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF application that is using a WindowsFormsHost control to host a control of Windows.Forms.

I tried to implement the MouseWheel event - but it seems that the the MouseWheel event never fired.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Have you first tried focusing the control before trying to mouse wheel over it?

Comment: i don't understand? where should i to set it? on c'tor? on WindowsFormsHost is loaded? - can u supply little code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround is to use event MouseEnter.

Suppose you have a winform label in a WindowsFormHost

In XAML

```
<WindowsFormsHost Height="100" Name="windowsFormsHost1" Width="200" />
```

In C#

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label label = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
label.Text = "Hallo";`
label.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(label_MouseEnter);
label.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(label_MouseWheel);
windowsFormsHost1.Child = label;
```

.....

```
void label_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Label).Focus();
}

void label_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as System.Windows.Forms.Label).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

Now MouseWheel should work (label shoud change color)

Comment: After finding so complicated things on the net, finally a simple and efficient solution ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

one thing im gonna add...
if a child of WindowsFormsHost is a Windows.Forms element then this link helps.

http://vastpark-svn.cvsdude.com/public/trunk/src/Sample.Client/WPFInputSource.cs

why im posting is i was looking for a solution and found.. so i thought it might be helpful somebody in the future.
anyway, thanks for asking here first^^