# How to capture mouse click event inside WindowsFormsHost control?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, windowsformshost

I have a user control with a WindowsHostControl that hosts a 3rd party video control.  I want to be able to capture mouse click event when mouse is clicked on the video.  I tried attaching an event to WindowsFormsHost control, but it never triggers.  How do I go about intercepting the mouse click?

Comment: Perhaps it is a problem similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807032/mousewheel-event-in-windowsformshost/9807775#9807775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by attaching event handler to the Child element contained inside WindowsFormsHost.

Answer (score 0):

Capture PreviewMouseDown instead.

Comment: That's not working either.  I think the problem is the video control I am trying to click is stealing mouse events.  It also doesn't expose Click event.  A workaround I just found is placing a transparent Label control on top of the video control, and handling its Click events instead.

Comment: If you're going that route, just use the adorner layer, so you don't have to maintain the label location